# How to get Citrix Remote Desktop to span multiple monitors

Tags: rdp, citrix

The company I work for uses Citrix Receiver to handle our remote desktop (Windows 7 sadly).  As far as I can tell, we aren't using XenDesktop (I've found solutions to this problem for that). We use version 4.1.0.56461 [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEqNy.png).  Receiver itself looks like this: [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCFXL.png).  When I open Remote Desktop and go to Display, there is no option to allow multiple screens: [Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLMru.png).  Whenever I'm remoted in, it doesn't allow me to change the number of screens or anything.  I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/588667/span-on-multiple-monitors-when-logged-into-a-citrix-session-via-citrix-receiver) thread with the same issue, however the accepted answer says something about modifying a .ica file, and I can't figure out where that is.  When I first open receiver, I just provide the server name and my username and password.

I also don't have a chrome plugin installed.

Is there a confirg file or something I can change somewhere that will allow me to have multiple desktops?  When I'm at my desk at work I have two screens and I have two screens at home, so it's painful to only be able to use one.

Comment: Try to move the Citrix-Receiver window so that part of it is on each screen. Then maximize that window. (Sounds weird, I know.) Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, but I could be wrong, this was configured in the back-end (Citrix server side) to publish a multi-monitor RDP application as seen from my Citrix session below.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  I asked our IT guy if it was possible and he just said "it's not possible with our current version"